# SQL List all of MemberID's of people who arent in the ones listed

Tags: sql, ms-access

[Outputted Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tfn1s.png)
[image: Design View]

I have a seperate Members table which has all the members ID's and I want to list all those but get rid of the ones that are displayed in this list.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl_classregistration.ClassID, tbl_classregistration.MemberID
FROM tbl_member INNER JOIN (tbl_classes 
INNER JOIN tbl_classregistration ON 
           tbl_classes.ClassID = tbl_classregistration.ClassID) ON              
           tbl_member.MemberID = tbl_classregistration.MemberID
GROUP BY tbl_classregistration.ClassID, tbl_classregistration.MemberID
HAVING (((tbl_classregistration.ClassID)=[Enter ClassID]));
```

Thats the SQL View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use not in:

```
select memberid from members where memberid not in (SELECT DISTINCT tbl_classregistration.MemberID
FROM tbl_member INNER JOIN (tbl_classes INNER JOIN tbl_classregistration ON tbl_classes.ClassID = tbl_classregistration.ClassID) ON tbl_member.MemberID = tbl_classregistration.MemberID
GROUP BY tbl_classregistration.ClassID, tbl_classregistration.MemberID
HAVING (((tbl_classregistration.ClassID)=[Enter ClassID])))
```

Comment: Thanks you. how do I get it to only display the first column which is MemberId though instead of all the members?

Comment: Write 'select memberid' instead of 'select *'

Comment: could you edit your answer and add it please cause im getting an error? thank you

Comment: If I wanted to use " Forms![ClassRegistration]![txt_classid] " instead of a parameter toretrieve the value how would i do that? so in the next list box it would display all the results